# How to delete a droplet backup on DigitalOcean?

Tags: digital-ocean, controlpanel, backups

Does the DigitalOcean control panel offer a way to delete a backup that has been made for a deleted droplet?  (NB: backup, not snapshot)

I created a droplet, enabling backups, and deleted it only a few minutes later.  DigitalOcean made a backup of the droplet just before completing the deletion.  So now I have a backup with no corresponding droplet.  I'm being charged for the backup, and would like to delete it.

ADDENDUM:  The control panel offers an option to convert the backup to a snapshot.  When I did that, the backup disappeared, but it re-appeared a short time later, after I had deleted the snapshot.  This left me right back where I started from.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your backups are deleted when your droplet is destroyed, make sure that **"Scrub Data"** is checked.

[image: DO Control Panel]

On DigitalOcean, you can not manually delete an individual backup. Backups are automatically generated, and will be automatically destroyed after a period of a few days once the droplet has been destroyed. As the price of enabling backups is calculated as 20% of the price of the running droplet, you are not charged extra after the droplet is destroyed.

Snapshots, on the other hand, are generated on demand and will persist after a droplet is destroyed until you delete it manually from the [**Images** page of the DigitalOcean control panel.](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/images)

If for some reason, you need to ensure that the back is destroyed sooner and you didn't check  "Scrub Data" [just open a support ticket](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/support) and the DO team can do it for you.